# MySQL/MariaDB Order rows by score

Tags: mysql, performance, select, mariadb

I have a table that has about 13 millions rows and my primary key is an hexadecimal value `VARBINARY(16)`.

I use the follow query to get my results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbip 
WHERE ip_start <= INET6_ATON('XXX.XX.XX.XX') 
  AND addr_type = 4 
ORDER BY ip_start DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

But this query take about 0,1 seconds and it should be about 0,02 seconds or less.

99% of my bandwidth is in Brasil who is just 131.270 rows, I have the column `country` in my database. So what can I do to search this ip first in Brasil, after in the rest of the table? Do you think this way I will gain some milliseconds ?

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE `dbip` 
(
    `addr_type` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `ip_start` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `ip_end` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL,
    `country` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    `stateprov` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `latitude` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `longitude` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `timezone_offset` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `timezone_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `isp_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `connection_type` VARCHAR(8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `organization_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ip_start`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This is an real time data so it must be fast. I also accept suggestions to change my database, I tried some with in memory storage but it do not accept binary values as index or they don't me allow to use `<=` command

Comment: what is your table schema!?

Comment: How did you determine that your query time should be "0,02 seconds or less"?

Comment: @BobJarvis - System minimum requirement. I need this to be better performance as possible

Comment: @Alex - I've edited my post. `addr_type` can be ipv4 or ipv6. Thank you

Comment: I guess according to your schema `ip_start VARBINARY(16)` you save ip address as string but not int. I think that is not best idea, and can't get how you can compare that string vs `INET6_ATON` does it work at all?

Comment: @Alex I'm not able to save an ipv6 as int, just ipv4 so I convert both ipv6 and ipv4 to binary and search for it.

Comment: not sure, but just if you have possibility to experiment you can try: `ALTER TABLE dbip ADD INDEX idx (ip_start, addr_type);
ALTER TABLE dbip ADD INDEX addr_type (addr_type);` and run query again

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty pour schema and need more optimisation.

First, you must INDEX everything that deems feasible for immediate reference and also grouping.  Index the country code itself will cut down the select time, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM dbip 
  WHERE 
  country="BR"
  AND addr_type = 4 
  AND ip_start <= INET6_ATON('XXX.XX.XX.')
  ORDER BY ip_start DESC;
```

will narrow down the select to 131270 row.  The add_type index will cut the searching further.

Second, normalised those repetitive value, otherwise , you will end up having trouble maintain the data integrity (imagine some store the city name with typo). In addition, loading huge chunk of data into DBMS take lots of resources. Yes, it is "inconvenient" to left join those data, it will save you in the long run. Without normalisation, each row will occupy at least 530 bytes , if the  result return 50k rows, then 530bytes x 50k = easily 25MB before aggregation (Before Order by sorting)

Without the `LIMIT 1`, this query will definitely take more than few minutes, since it try to traverse the whole 13 millions row, aggregate huge data to memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since virtually all entries are for Brazil, we can probably ignore the `country`.

```
WHERE addr_type = 4 
  AND ip_start <= INET6_ATON('XXX.XX.XX.')
  ORDER BY ip_start DESC;
```

needs

```
INDEX(addr_type, ip_start)
```

Specifically start with the "= constant", then move on to the 'range'.  The `ORDER BY` should be consumed in the same optimization.

If, instead, you add `AND country = 'BR', then you need:

```
INDEX(country, addr_type, ip_start)
```

(`country` and `addr_type` can be in either order, but `ip_start` must be last.)

You could get rid of type, since `LENGTH(INET6_ATON(...))` is 4 or 16, depending on whether it is IPv4 or IPv6, respectively.

I don't think your original query should not have taken that long.  Please do this for further debugging:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```